# Why does mechanical energy transform into heat when there is a loss of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy

I was studying for a mechanics test, I didn't understand why when there is friction, the energy transforms to a heat. In reality it does, but how can we show it mathematically ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Friction is caused due to interaction of surface asperities. The friction between two mating surfaces in relative motion causes loss of mechanical energy which results in heat. 
Let $W$ be the work done on a body of mass $m$ moving with velocity $v$ then the loss of mechanical energy or work done in form of heat  is given by the law of conservation of energy as follows
$$Q_{\text{loss}}=W-\frac{1}{2}mv^2=W-K.E.$$

$$\text{Heat generated}=\text{Loss in Mechanical energy}$$

Comment: This is not correct. $Q$  in the first law is not heat due to friction. $Q$ is energy transfer between the system and surroundings solely due to temperature difference between them. In fact friction is not a heating process.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right. I modified the answer.You may check it now

Comment: @Bob_D if there are work sources present during heat transfer then there is no operational way of deciding whether the "heat" Q was transferred solely due to temperature difference or not. This is especially the case if the process is internally dissipative. In fact, if the process is isothermal at the thermostat temperature then there is no temperature difference while entropy may flow in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

You can express it in a formula, but it is an experimental fact. The bodies heated by friction can be put in a calorimeter just after the event. And the energy be compared with the work done.

Comment: This is not correct. The bodies are not "heated by friction". Friction increases the internal energy of the bodies due to work transfer, which in turn increases the temperature of the bodies.